# Why does JAGS require at least two chains to calculate DIC?

Tags: r, jags

I'm trying to understand how JAGS calculates deviance and the [Deviance Information Criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_information_criterion) (DIC).

The `dic.samples` function in `rjags` in R throws an error if you have only one chain.

```
stop("2 or more parallel chains required")
```

The formula for calculating DIC involves calculating the expected deviance and the deviance at the expected values of the parameters in the model. I imagine such estimates could be obtained from a single chain (albeit there might sometimes be convergence issues that can only be identified with more than one chain).

The manual states that:

> The pD monitor estimates the contribution to the effective number of
>   parameters (pD) [3] from an observed stochastic node by comparing the
>   deviance deviance across multiple chains [1]. It is created by using
>   the option type(pD). If the model has only one chain then a pD monitor
>   cannot be defined.

So my question is:

- Why does JAGS require at least two chains to calculate DIC?
- Or more specifically, why does the pD monitor require two chains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to calculate pD - the method that JAGS uses is described by Martyn Plummer in the Discussion to the 'Bayesian measures of model complexity and fit' paper:
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9868.00353/abstract

Get the PDF and then do a search for 'Plummer' - the first result gives the details of the calculation used in JAGS.